# How to detect when an observable sequence hasn't produced a value after some time

Tags: rxjs

I have an observable that throttles `dragover` events by 350ms and returns `true` as long as those events keep coming in:

```
Rx.Observable
  .fromEvent(document, 'dragover')
  .map(function () { return true; })
  .throttle(350)
  .distinctUntilChanged()
```

I want to know if there hasn't been a dragover event withinin the last 350ms and return `false` when that happens. How should I go about doing that?

Do I need to have a separate timer and reset it whenever a `dragover` event occurs? I'm hoping that I can keep this stateless.

Answer (score 3):

There is an operator called `timeout` that does this.

```
Rx.Observable
  .fromEvent(document, 'dragover')
  .throttle(350)
  .map(true)
  .timeout(350, Rx.Observable.just(false))
  .distinctUntilChanged();
```

A note that `timeout` will unsubscribe from the source `Observable` and subscribe with the one you passed in, so you won't get any further results from that `Observable` until your resubscribe to it.

Also I would recommend that you put the `map` operation *after* the `throttle` in order to avoid unnecessary mapping operations of values you won't use.

And I would suggest thinking about if those timings are really what you want, since you are throttling over 350ms, timing out on 350ms leaves some pretty narrow margins. 1/3 of a second is not a lot of time to react especially for users. Since you already have a downstream `distinctUntilChanged` you may not even need to throttle since you will only be emitting values when it goes from true to false.

**Edit**

If you need the `Observable` to continue you can use `doWhile` or `repeat` to resubscribe (I used mousemove for my tests):

```
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(window, 'mousemove')
 .map(true)
 .timeout(1000, Rx.Observable.just(false))
 .repeat()//.doWhile(function() { return true; })
 .distinctUntilChanged()
 .subscribe(function(value) { console.log(value); });

//Outputs
/* Mouse starts moving */
// true 

/* Mouse stopped moving for 1 second */
// false

/* Mouse still not moving no emit */

/* Mouse starts moving again */
// true
```

Comment: I like this solution a lot more than the one I just posted. I tried the timeout operator before but ran into the problem you just described about it unsubscribing from the source. Is there a clean way to resubscribe?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I ended up solving my own question. I removed the throttle operator. It was redundant because the browser throttles the `dragover` event by 350ms anyway.

I created a source for dragover "start" events and a source for dragover "end" events. I gave both timestamps so that an end event's create time can be compared to a start event's create time:

```
var dragoverStart$ = Rx.Observable
  .fromEvent(this.dom, 'dragover')
  .timestamp()
  .pluck('timestamp');

var dragoverEnd$ = dragoverStart$
  .delay(350);

Rx.Observable
  .combineLatest(dragoverStart$, dragoverEnd$)
  .map(function (timestamps) {
    return timestamps[0] > timestamps[1];
  })
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .subscribe(function (isDragging) {
    // ...
  });
```